# Solving Ax=By without inverting matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I need to solve an equation in the form Ax=By for x. I know I shouldn't solve it by inverting B but I couldn't solve B^-1Ax=y with `scipy.gmres` or `linalg.solve` since it fails when I try to invert B with `linalg.inv`. It returns the error message "`Singular matrix`".

Is there any other way to invert a matrix?  Efficiency is not important since I need to do it just once. I dont want to solve the equation twice like first for T=Ax and then x.

Comment: `np.linalg.solve(A, B @ y)`?

Comment: A,B= 2^16x2^16 x,y=2^16x1. A, B and y are given matrices. Then I have to multiply B and y 2^12 times. It is a loop.

Comment: `np.linalg.solve` is O(N^3) when A is NxN, so in your case this translates to at least 2^54 operations, which should take at least 70 days at 3 GHz, probably much longer. If A is sparse, symmetric, etc. you could look for a dedicated solver.

Comment: It is sparse, that's why I want to use scipy.gmre for ( B^-1*A)x=y.

Comment: Perhaps `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A, B.multiply(y))` where `A`, `B` and `y` are csr?

Comment: Or `scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres(A, B.multiply(y))`.

Comment: If you really really want to "invert" singular matrix then you can use Penrose psudoinverse implemented in numpy.linalg.pinv()

Answer (score 1):

I'd join the suggestion of user [hilberts-drinking-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4585963/hilberts-drinking-problem) and not invert `B` but follow a two step approach: First multiply `B` and `y` to yield a vector `By` and then solve the system `A·x=By`. The following illustrates this approach using small arrays as test data:

```
from numpy import array;
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
from scipy.sparse.linalg import gmres

A = coo_matrix((3, 3), dtype=float)
A.setdiag( [ 2, 4, -1 ] )
A.setdiag( [ 2, -0.5 ], 1 )
print( "A", A )

B = coo_matrix((3, 2), dtype=float)
B.setdiag( [ 1, -2 ] )
B.setdiag( [ -0.5, 4 ], -1 )
print( "B", B )

y = array( [ 13, 5 ] )
print( "y", y )

By = B * y
print( "By", By )

x = gmres( A, By )
print( "x", x )
```